# Recursively replace characters in a python3 dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have seen lots of answers around replacing a particular character in a dictionary recursively. But those are dictionaries within dictionaries.

I'm looking for a solution to recursively replace certain characters or words in all the values of a python dictionary, but the dictionary values can be a string, int, dict or array. Example,

```
pydict = {
  'type': 'identity1',
  'desc': ['tan', 'grey', 'blue_brown'],
  'location': {
    'warehouse': "area '1'",
    'warehouse2': 'area 2'
  },
  'quant': 2
}

replacement_dict = {'tan': 'orange', "'": '"', '2': '3'}
```

So every word or character that matches in the key of replacement_dict in the pydict value I would like to replace with the replacement_dict value.

Comment: I would be nice if you added an expected outcome, especially since you have both `'2'` and `2` in your data and `'3'` in your replacement values. Do you expect something to happen in `quant`?

Comment: Try to show what you have done so far

Comment: Interesting. Google the same problem but use ‚json‘ instead of Python. Meanwhile I’ll try some things...

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty simple, you first handle all the cases where you want to deepen your recursion, i.e. lists and dicts, then just apply the replacement. I have assumed that all actual data is of type string, but I’m sure You can handle more cases (I just don’t want to type them out). Code below.

```
pydict = {'type': 'identity1', 'desc': ['tan', 'grey', 'blue_brown'], 'location': {'warehouse': "area '1'", 'warehouse2': 'area 2'}, 'quant': 2}

replacement_dict = {'tan': 'orange', "'": '"', '2': '3'}

def replace_rec(d):
    if type(d)==list:
        d = [replace_rec(x) for x in d]
    elif type(d)==dict: 
        for k in d.keys():  
            d[k] = replace_rec(d[k])
    else:
        for k, v in replacement_dict.items():   
           d = str(d).replace(k,v)
    return d

r = replace_rec(pydict)
print(pydict)
print(r)
```